# How to create bookmark in DOMPDF?

Tags: pdf, dompdf

I have generate pdf with DOMPDF and how can we generate bookmark in the pdf file?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in the current version, but you can submit a feature request in the [tracker](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/list).